My Electron JS-powered web application logs out the user session after 18 days
My Electron JS-powered web application logs out the user session after 18 days. Does Electron JS clear cache or cookies by default?
If so, how can this be prevented?
With or without restarting the PC, the web application (Google Voice) returns to its login page. I encounter this issue on multiple machines.
There's no cache or cookies management in the Electron JS application code.
Bye.
